# Consulta usando INNER JOIN com problema

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo uma consulta usando `INNER JOIN`, porém quando faço o `JOIN` na tabela `A` com a `B` e não não existe o id na tabela `B`, ele me retorna um `array` vazio. Gostaria que se ele não encontrasse o id na tabela `B` retornasse a tabela `A` mesmo assim ou as duas mas com os campo em branco na tabela `B`. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
SELECT *
FROM projects AS p
INNER JOIN project_images AS img ON p.id = img.project_id
WHERE p.id = 44
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Coloca a estrutura das tabelas, por gentileza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque o `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Valeu cara funcionou. Poderia me explicar qual a diferença entre o INNER E LEFT?

Comment: @LeandroCosta Veja esta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-e-a-diferenca-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado cara!

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do @Rodrigo Rigotti

INNER JOIN retorna registros de duas tabelas, por exemplo A e B, quando um registro com ID em A é igual a um registro com ID estrangeiro em B. Exemplo

```
... A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID_A ...
```

somente retornará registros que combinem em ambas as tabelas.

LEFT JOIN retorná TODOS os registros da tabela à esquerda do teste. Então se:

```
... A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID_A ...
```

retornará todos os registros de A, para aqueles onde B tenha o ID_A que combine, os campos de B serão preenchidos com este registro, para aqueles onde não existe ID_A que combine, os campos de B estarão com valor nulo.